# Jenkins global security swap

Tags: security, jenkins, global, configure

I am currently using project based matrix for Jenkins global security management. I am planning to change that to Role based strategy I got the plugin installed but the thing is I don't want to lock out all the users for this update. is there a safe way to do it without having to lock out all the users while moving from project based to role based strategy. we are using AWS Ec2 instance for jenkins if that helps? Is there an option to clone the repo and do something.

Thank you.